# Whats the best way to deploy predefined data via api calls?

Tags: json, api, rest, seed

I have several json files that represent the payload for different API's(I can map which API to call based on the file name, but other methods could be applied as well),
what is the best practice to populate my data on the application with the help of those json files?

My first though was to use some automation framework(rest assured for example) to accomplish my task, but I think it might be an overkill for my scenario.

p.s. snapshot of DB/query direct to DB is not an option because of the nature of the application.

Comment: Sounds like a combo of `fetch()` and `JSON.parse()` to me, maybe thrown in a loop.